# ArcPy RemoveLayer removes all layers in loop

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to remove layers that are not found within a list. The loop iterates through the layers within the Map_Left data frame. However, when I run this, it removes all of the layers within the data frame! Any explanation why?

```
preserved_layers = ("Major Roads", "Secondary Roads", "Water Features", "Rivers / Streams")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", Map_Left):
    if lyr.name not in preserved_layers:
        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(Map_Left, lyr)
```

Comment: I tried the same script and it seems to work fine. Are you sure you are properly referencing the dataframe Map_Left?

Comment: Code works fine for me. What are you assigning to Map_Left and mxd?

Comment: The code here looks correct to achieve your desired outcome. I know it is equivalent, but if it were me, I would maybe define the preserved_layers tuple as a list instead, and try again.

Comment: Are these group layers or individual layers?

Comment: @recurvata - Sorry for the late reply. I believe these are group layers, but I don't know for sure. Would that make a difference? I even tried supplying a conditional else statement for those that were not in the list, and the printout was as what I would have expected - those not in the list.

Comment: Map_Left = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

Comment: mxd =arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:/Users/name/US_11x17_Landscape_2_Maps.mxd")

Comment: @user1185790 edit the question directly to update it and not in the comments